Not able to patch CONFIG_BOOTDELAY for imx8 yocto build properly
I am trying to do boot optimization for imx8 in that process I want to remove bootdelay from 3 to 0. I am able to apply patch to the uboot but it was not working as expected.
Steps followed:
$ bitbake-layers create-layer meta-custom
$ bitbake-layers add-layer meta-custom
$ mkdir -p meta-custom/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-imx
$ nano meta-custom/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-imx_%.bbappend
Pasted this in file
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://my-uboot-config.cfg"

do_configure:prepend() {
    cat ${WORKDIR}/my-uboot-config.cfg >> ${B}/.config
}

$ nano meta-custom/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-imx/my-uboot-config.cfg
CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=0
bitbake u-boot-imx
bitbake imx-image-full
After following this process I see CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=0 is getting appended at the end of the .config file. In the same file, CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=3 is already present.
So if I boot the board it was picking delay of 3. Needed help with what is going wrong in this.

This is not the proper way to patch it. For properly doing this you have to create a patch file, in diff format. And then add it with SRC_URI, then it will automatically patched up. You don't need do_configure:prepend().

Why do you tag this question as C?  I cannot see any C code mentioned, discussed or similar.  Please, take the C tag off from it.

@rakib_ can you please help me in elaborating the process to do. I didn't get clear picture to do it.

@Srikanth Please familiarize yourself with diff, if you are using git repo, then can create a commit with your changes. And take that patch and apply like I said.

There are different ways to do it like patching or modifying it via devtool, better is to learn these techniques. In case , you don't understand it, please try do_configure:append() instead of do_configure:prepend(), maybe it will work. Becuase prepend inserts the configuration before do_configure and in do_configure, kernel overwrite your bootoption. So, try the append option, it will modify your configuration after kernel has done with the configurations
